# Transactional API - MessageBuildError problem when sending multiple emails to same subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, transactional-messaging-api

I'm using the MC Transactional API for email and have run into a problem when trying to send multiple emails using the same send definition to the same subscriber.

The use-case is when we send vouchers. There are occasions when the customer purchases multiple vouchers and requests them all to be sent to their email address. In this case, our system sends multiple requests to the same send definition with the same subscriber details for each. The body of the payload is different per email. The requests all send within seconds of each other. **Note that MessageKey is unique for each request.**

When I try to do this I get an error via ENS for all the requests with a 103: MessageBuildError and no other info. I suspected it might be to do with the multiple requests to the same subscriber, so tested the same workflow but only sending one request as it worked fine (I also tested it in Postman to be sure and this also worked).

I recall a random conversation I had a while back with salesforce where they said something about de-duplication of email sends when trying to do what I am trying to do above. Does anyone know if such de-duplication exists? Can you point me in the right direction of where its documented our explain how it works?

Or is this not and thing and my MessageBuildError is something else entirely?

Comment: So you can reproduce the behavior with multiples using Postman?

Comment: MessageBuildError indicates a problem with the email scripting and/or the context of what's being sent in the payload.

Comment: Adam, you were right. It was an issue with one of the payloads in the batch. I just got lucky with the few I tested. In this case, there was ampscript looking for a json object but the value in the DE field was simply "null", this causing the issue. It is a shame that the error returned by MC is often so vague :( My bug-bear is the "does not match field type" error, but it doesn't tell me WHICH field!